# Running two versions of java at same time

Tags: java, path, artifactory, java-home

I have to use two versions of java (1.6.21 and 1.7).My company's code is dependent on 1.6_21 and we are planning to use artifactory. We are testing artifactory locally.But artifactory needs java 1.7 or higher.I want my default java home to point to 1.6_21 and for artifactory it should be 1.7.

But the problem is as soon as I install java 7,it sets itself as default.I have read many posts that explain how to manage two versions of java,but my artifactory and eclipse have to run at same time.

Please help!!

Comment: I'm wondering how don't you run java source code v6 with JRE 7?! you cannot run an embed library that has started with JRE7 with another version, unless you start it in separated process

Comment: "... unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming". Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Prashant How I read it, the question is "How do I configure Java so that I can run two different programs with two different versions of Java". That is a question for SuperUser. There doesn't seem to be a programming challenge here, or at least I fail to see it.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Very reasonable. I don't know Java much at all, so my lack of domain knowledge might have led me astray. I was drawn to "company's code" and "artifactory" (some sort of repository manager?) and "eclipse", which I don't use. I thought the last two might fall under "tools for programming"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use batch script (Windows) or a shell script (Linux) to execute artifactory, and set JAVA_HOME to the path of the Java version you want to execute

Comment: I generally run artifactory by executing artifactory.bat.Should i add a different java_home there?@morgano

Comment: Yes @user2242019, try editing that one

Answer (score 5):

This better be on linux or else good luck.

Install `java6` in `/usr/java/java6/` and install `java7` in `/usr/java/java7/`

Put something like this in your `.bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/java6/
export PATH='$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

alias java6='export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/java6/"; export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
alias java7='export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/java7/"; export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Then open a terminal run `java7` then start up artifactory for everything else you will be fine with 1.6.